# Profile page on some Sites don't show link to Meta User page

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

I recently joined to the [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) Beta site, and I noticed that *there is no link to my meta user on the user tab*:

[image]

However, this does show up on other Beta and non-Beta sites I frequent, like [Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

**What is the reason for this behavior?**

I guess I can access the Meta Site by going to the SE Icon on the Top bar and navigating to that site (or directly typing the URL), but *I find this link more accessible and straightforward to use*.

Currently, I only saw this on Project Management, so *perhaps* it has something to do with Beta sites... but in that case why does the Board & Card Games show the missing link?

Comment: Have you ever visited the child meta of that site? If not, you don't have an account on the meta site... you're not a "Meta user", so you don't have a link. :D That actually tells us whether you've ever used meta before

Comment: @Catija I *did* visit the meta site... but perhaps it was too recent and the link doesn't show up yet? (caching again?)

Comment: I see it on your account right now... so probably caching. :) I *don't* see it on mine, which I just created and I've never gone to their meta.

Comment: @Catija yup, I also see it now (undocumented feature?)... what should we do with this Post then?

Comment: Your call... I (or someone with more time) can answer it... or you can delete it... or answer it yourself with the info I've given you already and a guess about caching.

Comment: @Catija I'll leave it stay. An answer explaining what you exposed could be useful if future users witness the same thing and wonder about this (the "tells us whether you've ever used meta before" part).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A meta user isn't automatically created when you join a main site; it's only created once you actually visit meta (while logged in to your main account). So if you haven't visited meta before you won't have a meta account and therefore there'll be no link to it.

You can see the effect of this just by looking the number of users on a main site vs the number of users on that site's meta. As an example (using the API to get the number of users)...

[Graphic Design has 70k+ users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!*Mx9r.U-F7TXfo*p&site=graphicdesign&run=true)... But [Graphic Design Meta only has 4k+ users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#filter=!*Mx9r.U-F7TXfo*p&site=graphicdesign.meta&run=true)

Answer (score 5):

You only see that link if you've visited the per-site meta while logged in before. (It may take a few minutes for that link to appear after you visit, due to caching.)

This is useful to other users as it is a public indication as to whether or not you've ever visited the per-site meta.