# How have more people edited their profiles on main sites than on per-site metas?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, per-site-meta

Look [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer) at Autobiographer on main OR Stack Exchange:

> Complete "About Me" section of user profile.
>
> Awarded 484 times.

Look at [the meta site's equivalent of the badge](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer):

> Awarded 166 times.

This same thing happens on other sites.

Looking at my other account that can't participate in the meta on one site, its bio on meta certainly exists. **How are there users who have edited their main but not meta profiles?**

Comment: Could this also be related to the bug where autobiographies are no longer getting automatically copied? See: ["Autobiographer" badge not being awarded when information is automatically filled in - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353640/autobiographer-badge-not-being-awarded-when-information-is-automatically-fille)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[A meta site profile is created only when the user visits meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306836)

So, it's not that they edited main but not meta -- it's just that they don't have a meta profile.

Comment: Oh! That is true!! Testing trying to go to my newly-linked account meta profile on a site while not logged in finds an error.