# "Autobiographer" badge not being awarded when information is automatically filled in

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

This query:

[# of a specific badge, for a single user networkwide - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/962580/of-a-specific-badge-for-a-single-user-networkwide?badgename=Autobiographer&AccountID=12266974)

shows that on 5 sites (and their 5 metas) I don't have the "Autobiographer" badge, even though my information was automatically copied when I joined those sites:

[image]

I've never had to do anything special for this badge before.  Has something broken?

Comment: Looks like the flag for whether the user has an AboutMeExcerpt is not being set to `true` properly when creating new profiles, which is what the badge script looks at in order to award Autobiographer. This also has the side-effect of making the user popup (on hovering their profile picture) not appear because the code thinks you don't have one.

Comment: We're going to look into this as part of our regular bug duty rotation. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 5):

We rolled out a fix for this and also put in an automated test so this should be harder to break from now on. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Note that if you previously didn't earn the badge as a result of this bug, you must make an edit to your profile to earn it. In other words, badges will not be retroactively awarded.

Comment: Will users be retroactively awarded badges automatically if they were supposed to have earned them in the past?

Comment: No, but if there are any edits to the profile it will award the badge if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to post something very similar! :)

The bug does get very annoying, I have to go into every single one of my SE site's profile pages and make a small edit in order to individually get this badge.

Hopefully, the bug is fixed soon and you can press the "save and copy changes to all public communities" and automatically get the Autopbiographer badge whenever you join a new site.