# Couldn't go to the Code Golf meta

Tags: bug

I have registered for Code Golf. I wanted to go to the meta, but write me that I have to enter. If you press Log in, you transfer me to the main page and nothing happens. If I click on Sign up and Confirm new account transfers to https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/openidconfirm where it says Page not found

Comment: Not sure it's connected to your bug, but you do appear to have multiple profiles on code golf (a [known rare bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310019/681403)). You should probably get those merged.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062281/users-accountid-duplications

Comment: @Someone_Evil you are probably right according to the query ^

Comment: I'm pretty sure you aren't supposed to have to login to the per-site meta specifically (it comes automatically if you're logged in on the main), but attempting to do so it littered with 404 bugs (eg. ["Join this community" gives 404 when called from add comment on a site meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269699), [404 when trying to login on per-site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210945)). If you are logged into the main site, the meta profile [should be created upon visiting the meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306836/681403).

Comment: Most likely something on your end is blocking cookies. Disable it or whitelist the site you want to use, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard it didn't help. problem remained

Comment: OK, you're "victim" of a known bug. [This is your profile on Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99104/danis), which is broken somehow, as you see it's showing two accounts for Code Golf. I'd look for the original bug report and link to it, you can decide if you want to close as duplicate.

Comment: [Here it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310019/why-do-some-users-have-two-site-accounts-each-tied-to-the-same-network-profile). While not direct duplicate, whatever bug causing this most likely also cause you can't login to the site meta.

Answer (score 2):

As said so in the comments, your profile on Code Golf is showing two accounts. We don't know why yet, but whatever caused that bug is most likely causing this bug here. Also, your other profile appears to have a Russian name there.

Perhaps the system is confused about which account you should set up for. Or, however, you could have created the new account when you tried to click "Sign up" on meta.